# How do I Purchase AWS t2.medium Reserved instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-reserved-instances

I create new Account on AWS. In start I Purchase t2.micro free instance and running my website. Now I want to use the and Purchase t2.medium Reserved instance,Standard,No Upfront for 36 months .
But When I try to Place Order, I received following error....

"Error: Your current quota does not allow you to purchase the required number of reserved instances (Status Code: 400; Error Code: ReservedInstancesLimitExceeded; Request ID: 8b7becc4-5b90-455d-8dde-b54c30961cff)"

What is the solution of above error on AWS Reserved Instance.
Plz give me solution.

I try to Purchase Reserved instance and Place order but my order fail to proceed on AWS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you’ve had your AWS account for less than about a month, then you cannot purchase reserved instances with No Upfront Cost. You’re too risky to receive the discount at this stage.

Amazon state:

**You're purchasing a No Upfront RI with a new AWS account.** AWS restricts the ability for new accounts to purchase No Upfront RIs. The restriction on purchasing No Upfront RIs is lifted automatically, usually after about a month.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-ri-buy-error/

Comment: I was just about to copy/paste the same link.  See also: https://repost.aws/questions/QUljcklSgiQmO9Hu9qN0FGxw/cant-purchase-the-first-reserved-instance.

Comment: Google is wonderful :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, AWS did not allow to Purchase  Reserved Instances with **NO UPFRONT** for new accounts due to risk of payments.
After 2  to 3 months they allowed for **AWS RI NO Upfront** to purchase.